# Writing cells from other notebooks into current notebook?

Tags: notebooks, cells

I have a large number of Mathematica notebooks which contain study notes for different topics (as opposed to actual Mathematica Code).

I'm trying to develop some code to randomly pull parts of a given notebook into the current notebook ... to use as a kind of flashcard system for reviewing notes.

I've gotten this far:

```
SetDirectory["/Users/Bill/Desktop/Notebooks"];
nb = NotebookOpen[FindFile["chemistry.nb"], Visible -> False];
sections = NotebookLookup[nb, "CellExpression", Cell[___, "Section", ___]];
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], RandomChoice[sections]]
```

This small amount of code, when evaluated, will write to the current notebook a random section heading cell, from the notebook `chemistry.nb`.

This is great ... but what I *actually* want to is write to the current notebook the section heading cell, and all the content cells beneath it  (Subsections, Items, ItemParagraphs, Text, etc).

Does anyone know how to do this?  There seems to be no built in documentation for `NotebookLookup`, I only discovered it when I came across this file: http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/AuthorTools/AuthorTools.pdf

Comment: I use Mathematica 9 and i dont have a function like `"NotebookLookup"` there are Functions like `NotebookFind` and `NotebookLocate` but in your case its better to work with `CellObjects` as I just recently learned. See my answer for details and dont forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: @sacratus Try ``<<AuthorTools` ``

Comment: @Kuba interesting, seems to be perfect for going deeper into notebook programming and creation. I'll have a closer look, when i reached the limitations of the build-in functionalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `SelectionMove`like this:

```
 SelectionMove[nb, Next, CellGroup]
```

or

```
SelectionMove[nb, All, CellGroup]
```

one of these should work in your case

**EDIT:**

Full Solution for an arbitrary notebook:

```
nb = CreateWindow[
DocumentNotebook[{CellGroup[{TextCell["Text Group", "Section"], 
   TextCell["Mary had a little lamb.", "Text"], 
   TextCell["Its fleece was white as snow.", "Text"]}], 
 CellGroup[{TextCell["Graphics Group", "Section"], 
   ExpressionCell[ Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -3, 3}], "Output"]}]}]];

sections = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Section"]
SelectionMove[RandomChoice[sections], All, CellGroup]
read = NotebookRead[nb];
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], read]
```

Comment: thanks @sacratus, this is exactly what I was looking for